It is allowed to ask "Big List" questions?
In Mathoverflow, people can ask
Big List questions which are "questions designed to generate a "big list" of certain results, examples, conjectures, etc. via many individual answers, each contributing one or a few instances."?
In particular, it implies that people are encourage to give relevant answers even many other ones have already been put.
If you want examples of such questions :
https://mathoverflow.net/questions/405177/open-problems-in-symbolic-dynamics
https://mathoverflow.net/questions/403359/theorems-with-finite-sets-of-exceptions
Is it authorized to ask such questions in this SE?
If yes, should it be flagged to be in Community Wiki mode (like in Mathoverflow)?
Can it be interesting to add a such tag?

Like these two? The backdoor of Telegram on Diffie-Hellman Key Exchange and possible other examples?, What are other good attack examples that use the hash collision?. Attacks Relying on Poor Entropy. If properly written, why not? Your links is rather a meta question for our community.

Note that that first DHKE example actually starts off with listing possible attacks in the quesetion. I would consider is better to put those in a (Wiki) answer instead. As I've also asked these kind of questions, e.g. Which attacks are possible against raw/textbook RSA?  I can hardly complain. Do try and make the question not overly broad though; i.e. put as many constraints on the list as possible. Note that this is my personal opinion; if these questions are condoned is up to the community.

(so if anybody wants to answer, please go ahead and we can vote on it, I have currently limited time and cannot think of a good post right now)

Bad questions, in my sense, are asking too many questions in one question, asking broad questions, very little/no information about the need of the question. If the answer is too long, the answer may be skipped by the community.

IMHO this is risky territory. Especially since we try to make answers not opinion based, and there can never be an accepted answer.
That said, I have actually asked for questions which ask for examples. But this is when it's clear there is no need to be comprehensive and that indeed an answer with 2-3 examples would be sufficient and continuing to add more after a certain point would be redundant and not actually add value.
A never ending question where people always add answers seems less desireable IMHO.
That said, I think all our rules shoud be enforced leniently when we think the question is high quality shows thought and could produce interesting answers. While novice questions with little effort spent should still be allowed but rules should be enforced more strictly.
